# Having trouble with merge function algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, merge, array-merge

I have been trying to figure out what could possibly be going wrong with the calling of these two functions for a while now and can't seem to identify it. When I call the merge function before the show function, it works fine and merges the two arrays and then shows them Otherwise, if I call the merge function after any other function (such as the show(a,els) and show(b,els)), the merge function does not work and outputs all zeroes in the merged array. Any ideas would be very helpful.

```
int main(){
    const unsigned els = 5;
    unsigned a[els] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned b[els] = {1,2,3,4,4};
    unsigned combo[(els*2)];

    show( a, els);
    show( b, els);

    merge( combo, a, els, b, els);
    show( combo, els*2);

    return 0;
}

void show( const unsigned a[], unsigned elements ){
    cout << "[" << elements << "]: ";
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < elements; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i]; //Outputting contents of array
        if(i != elements-1)
            cout << ","; 
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void merge( unsigned combo[], const unsigned a[], unsigned aElements, const
unsigned b[], unsigned bElements ){

    string notsort(" Array is not sorted");
    if((!sorted(a, aElements)) || (!sorted(b, bElements)))
        die(notsort);

    unsigned i,j,k = 0;
    while(i < aElements && j < bElements){
        if(a[i] <= b[j]){
            combo[k]= a[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            combo[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if(i < aElements){
        for(int x = i; x < aElements; x++){
            combo[k] = a[x];
            k++;
        }
    }else{
        for(int x = j; x < bElements; x++){
            combo[k] = b[x];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output with merge function after show of a and b:

```
[5]: 1,2,3,4,5
[5]: 1,2,3,4,4
[10]: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Output with merge function before show of a and b:

```
[10]:1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5
[5]: 1,2,3,4,5
[5]: 1,2,3,4,4
```

Comment: Enable heavy compiler warnings and pay attention to things like "Variable `i` is uninitialized when used here".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the `merge` function, because you don't initialize the `i` or `j` variables. That means their value is *indeterminate* (and in reality will be seemingly random).

When declaring variable, you need to initialize *every* variable separately, you can't do like you do now and hope all variables will be initialized.

So change from

```
unsigned i,j,k = 0;
```

to

```
unsigned i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, silly mistake but had to make it to learn from it. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Mihai Uninitialized global variables, as well as `static` local variables are zero-initialized. Non-static local variables are not initialized.